# How to make choose file window contain only .png and .jpeg files?

Tags: php, forms

I have a `buildForm` method:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('photo', 'file', array('label' => false, 'required'  => false));
}
```

How to make choose file window show only .png and .jpeg files?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: PHP i'd assume, possibly using Symphony.

Answer (score 5):

Use `accept` like:

```
<input type="file" accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg" />
```

Or in your case:

```
$builder->add('photo', 'file', array('label' => false, 'required'  => false,
    'accept' => ".png,.jpg,.jpeg" ));
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this should work:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('photo', 
                  'file', 
                  array('label' => false, 
                        'required' => false, 
                        'attr' => array('accept' => 'image/jpeg,image/png')
                  )
    );
}
```

The HTML for that is

```
<input type="file" accept="image/jpg,image/png">
```

However that's not supported by any browser.

Comment: I am using Symfony2 framework for this. But now I get this error:
The option "accept" does not exist. Known options are: "action", "attr", "auto_initialize", "block_name", "by_reference" .... blah blah blah